# How to set a conditional webform to copy the value of a field to another?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm trying to design a webform in Drupal 7. We have a separate entries for a "student postal address" and "guardian postal address". A request appeared to have a "use same address" check box.

Is there a way to attempt this without custom coding? Optimaly, I'd love to select the value of another field using the `Webform Conditional` UI shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[webform sameas](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_sameas)

> this module makes a "Same As" component available for use on your
>   webforms. This component allows you to add a "Same as" checkbox to a
>   form allowing you to indicates that one set of fields should have the
>   same value as another set of fields. For example, if you had fields
>   for both a Billing and Shipping address on your webform, you could add
>   the Same As component to allow users to only fill out their billing
>   address if their shipping address is the same.